# rails how to send http request with http authentication to a php file

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, http-authentication

I have a php file test.php which created HTTP Auth.

```
$valid_passwords = array ("test" => "test123");
        $valid_users = array_keys($valid_passwords);

        $user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
        $pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

        $validated = (in_array($user, $valid_users)) && ($pass == $valid_passwords[$user]);

        if (!$validated) {
          header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
          header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
          die ("Not authorized");
        }

        // If arrives here, is a valid user.
        echo "<p>Welcome $user.</p>";
        echo "<p>Congratulation, you are into the system.</p>";
            }
```

Now I want to visit that test.php and send a get request there from a rails platform, I have tried this:

```
url = 'http://url/test.php'
        uri = URI.parse(url)
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path,'Authorization' => "test test123")
        response = http.request(request)
        render :text => response.body
```

It doesn't work, says unauthorized.
I can do changes in PHP as well as Rails, I just need a secure way to make http requests between the two.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Details!

Comment: usernames can have spaces in them. how is rails to know that you're passing `"user password"`? Try `request.basic_auth("test", "test123")` instead.

Comment: @Kenneth , it says unauthorized,

Comment: @MarcB it gives me error: no implicit conversion of String into Integer, i did this: `response = http.request(request.basic_auth("test", "test123"))
  render :text => response.body`

Comment: hey it worked! i was it wrong way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
url = 'http://url'
        uri = URI.parse(url)
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path, 'Content Type' => 'application/json')
        request.basic_auth("test", "test123")
        response = http.request(request)
        render :text => response.body
```

thanks to MarcB